# Fixing a left leaning navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm making a website for a school club for my first starter front-end project and I've been using the bootstrap library for CSS. I've ran into a bit of a problem though, my navbar isn't centred horizontally and more so leans to the left. I wanted the title and icon all to the left then the list items on the other side of the container so I played around with margins but it never really worked out. Thank you for helping.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
      <div class="container"> 
            <a class="navbar-title" href="home.html">Title</span>
                <img class="navbar-brand" src="https://i.imgur.com/qRujsE0.jpg"></img>
            </a> 
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-btarget="#navmenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggle-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="home.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a</li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="join.html" class="nav-link">Join Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Edit your question to add a working **snippet**, where you can include just enough of your HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem to us.

Comment: In your<ul> element, instead of mx-auto try ms-auto instead. Also, you probably want to set a max-width on your icon as it's too big right now.

Comment: @BrettDonald I'm sorry I'm new here, how do I do that?

Comment: @CharlesFisher Hi! Do you mean the navbrand or the toggler when you say icon? I have a separate CSS file that handles the size of the navbrand. Also I've used ms-auto before and it got the same results as the mx-auto.

Comment: To add a snippet, when editing your question, use toolbar above the editor. The **seventh** icon from the left is the snippet tool. Just to the right of the image tool.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest to specify a width and a height to your image. Then, you have to use the class ".ms-auto" to get the navigation aligned on the right as per Boostrap documentation. You could have also used Bootstrap flexbox with the class ".justify-content-between".

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
    <div class="container"> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qRujsE0.jpg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="" />
            Title
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="home.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a</li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="join.html" class="nav-link">Join Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer, read [answer]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).